# how to find StickNumbers

Tags: java, numberformatexception

So I have to read a sequence of numbers from the console ( 1 to 50 numbers), none of which are equal and print out the numbers for which is true that a|b == c|d (example: 5|32 == 53|2), but I get an NubmferFormatException each time. Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StuckNumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // input count and declare array
    System.out.println("input number of numbers");
    int count = input.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[count];

    // check if count is between 1 and 50
    if (count < 1 && count > 50) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input. Input a number between 1 and 50");
        count = input.nextInt();
    }

    // input n numbers
    for (int i : numbers) {
        i = input.nextInt();
        // check if i = j
        for (int j : numbers) {
            if (i == j) {
                System.out
                        .println("All numbers must be dist75inct. Try again.");
                i = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            if (stuckNumbers(numbers[i], numbers[j]) == stuckNumbers(
                    numbers[j], numbers[i])) {
                System.out.println(i + "|" + j + " == " + j + "|" + i);
            }
        }
    }

    input.close();
}

public static int stuckNumbers(int a, int b) {
    String firstNum = "a";
    String secondNum = "b";
    String res = "ab";
    int result = Integer.parseInt(res);
    return result;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at these lines:

```
String res = "ab";
int result = Integer.parseInt(res);
```

"ab" is not a number, so you're going to get a NumberFormatException when you try to parse it as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the firstNum and SecondNum variables from "a" and "b" to `Integer.toString(a);` OR `String.valueOf(a);` and similar for b.

```
public static int stuckNumbers(int a, int b) {
String firstNum = String.valueOf(a);
String secondNum = String.valueOf(b);
String res = "";
res.concat(firstNum);
res.concat(secondNum);
int result = Integer.parseInt(res);
return result;
```

}

I hope this will remove any Exception being thrown.